# How can get internal memory File?

Tags: android, android-file, android-memory

i try to get internal memory file or path.but i cant do it.below codes not worked for me.

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = new File(cw.getFilesDir(), "Music");
directory.mkdirs();
File file = new File(directory, "aaa.mp3");
file.createNewFile();
file.mkdirs();
```

OR

```
File dir=Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory();
dir.createNewFile();
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "aaa.mp3");
file.createNewFile();
file.mkdirs();
```

OR

```
File dir=Environment.getDataDirectory();
dir.createNewFile();
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "aaa.mp3");
file.createNewFile();
file.mkdirs();
```

plz explain about getDirFiles().i read in same cases getDirFiles() worked.but i cant use it.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little late. If you have not find out the solution then just check my [same issue conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006081/filenotfoundexception-when-fetch-image-from-internal-storage/22008781#22008781) as yours .

Sometimes we write the perfect logic but still we face problem for some reasons.Like physical connection between device and compter which makes obstacle to fetch data from device.