# FileNotFoundException when fetch image from Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, file, filenotfoundexception

Files **==>** [image] **==>** [image]

As I'm showing in this picture flow, my image(960-Minimalism.jpg) is inside internal phone storage and I'm trying to get it's path for further use through File class.

> What I have tried yet

1st:

```
String filePath = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(filePath, "960-Minimalism.jpg");
```

2nd:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Android/data/"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
        + "/Files/"+"960-Minimalism.jpg");
```

The extreme hard code way:

```
File file = new File("/data/data/com.example.net/files/","960-Minimalism.jpg")
```

Exception here same as 1st..

I know I'm missing something or doing something wrong here but unable to find out till now.

Any Idea..

**EDIT**

Please don't think I have three problems . The above are my tried solutions which not worked. But problem is one that I want to fetch the image path which is in my internal storage memory. That's why I deleted my exceptions here.

Comment: Actually what is the path of your image file ?

Comment: Try this path `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "960-Minimalism.jpg");`

Comment: is your director "files" or "Files" ?

Comment: its Files..which is in main menu and all of us know it.. inside which my 1st image belongs to..

Comment: @RanjitPati, did you try the path ?

Comment: @Kedarnath ya I have already tried it .. same problem..

Comment: @RanjitPati, ok , When you are executing this, please remove your usb cable and then try again. Sometime where USB cable is attached, then phone can not use SD-card ( for some specific models )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of giving the path can you do other way round. Open the phone gallery and select the file that you need then get the file uri and use it. I had had similar problem and I had solved it that way. And sometime the file's extension is jpeg but it shows jpg there and gives error. If you could check the file detail for correct file 
extension

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +...(insert specific file path)
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
```

Now you have a bitmap that you can use. But be sure to call recycle()` method on bit once you are done to prevent memory leak.

And to get File Uri you can try following codes that I have directly pasted from one of my project

```
  Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

This will open the gallery for you to select image. And once you are done. Override onActivityResult method as below.

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
               Uri file = data.getData(); 
              }
else{
// no file selected
}
    }
```

You can use this file Uri for your image need. Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is i have to send the file..not the bitmap.anyways it is also a possible solution so i upvoted it..

Comment: Using the bitmap way. Save the bitmap and then once it is saved send the filepath and once saved destroy the bitmap.

Comment: I have changed a little in your answer and added here..thanks for a good suggestion .. your answer give me the solution path ,so I accepted it..

Answer (score 2):

```
Getting access to external storage
```

In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system permissions. For example:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

If you need to both read and write files, then you need to request only the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, because it implicitly requires read access as well.

Comment: He want to fetch data from internal storage not from external storage.

Comment: @InnocentKiller I can see  line at Exception here: (Permission denied)

Answer (score 2):

For your **2nd** problem add these two permissions to your `Manifest` file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: i have tried all above solutions..but my problem is one that how to fetch this image path successfully ..and unfortunately i forgot to add permissions..but add permission is not my solution..

Answer (score 1):

I just change a little as [1011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2041498/1011) suggested and get the solution.

**1st problem is the connected device(through data cable) which makes obstacle between memory storage and application. As i understand a physical connection prohibited the device to share its internal memory and also sdcard files.**

For the solution I followed 1011's answer and did like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

and inside `onActivityResult` I fetched the uri and tried to get the path with a little [modified way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath/9989900#9989900)..something like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
    File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
    File file1 = new File(file.getPath());
    if(imageFile.exists()){
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Exists..:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOooooooooo..:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }else {
        // no file selected
  }
}

//method to get the real path with file extension
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

The method `getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)` will help to get the real path with perfect **File Extension** .